# apache2 server showing me the current installed version in my azure vm even it is uninstalled

Tags: azure, ubuntu, apache2, azure-virtual-machine, putty

I have the Azure VM is of Linux (Ubuntu) -20.04.

Long back, installed the apache2 (version is 2.4.41). Now I have tried to uninstall apache2, nginx but when I enter apache2 -v command in the azure vm (putty) - it is still showing me the current version of that server. Why?

**Commands I used**:

```bash
sudo apt remove nginx
sudo apt remove apache2
sudo apt autoremove
apache2 -v
```

I already uninstalled right but why it is showing me?[image]

**Update**:

`which apache2` command told me the output `/usr/sbin/apache2`

[image]

I tried to delete apache2 from `/usr/sbin/` path, it shown me below output:

```bash
/sbin$ sudo apt remove apache2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package 'apache2' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 281 not upgraded.
```

If I enter `apache2 -v`, it shows me the current installed version:

```bash
/sbin$ apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2023-03-08T17:32:54
```

If you see color coding of the output in one of the above screenshot, it shows `apache2` color in green color. Green color determines the executable file or recognized data file.

***Is that just a executable file which is not installed? Am I Correct?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my virtual machine I have Apache server like below:

```c
sudo systemctl status apache2
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2023-11-28 16:45:09 UTC; 7min ago
       Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
   Main PID: 2955 (apache2)
      Tasks: 55 (limit: 19118)
     Memory: 17.3M
     CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
             ├─2955 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             ├─2957 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             └─2958 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

Nov 28 16:45:09 vm2 systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Nov 28 16:45:09 vm2 systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
imran123@vm2:~$ apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2023-10-26T13:54:09
```

[image]

To remove Apache, you can make use of below command:

```c
sudo systemctl stop apache2
sudo apt-get purge apache2
sudo apt-get autoremove
apache2 -v
```

***Output:***

```c
imrxxxx:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils libapr1 libaprutil1 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap libjansson4
  liblua5.2-0 ssl-cert
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 10 to remove and 34 not upgraded.
After this operation, 7575 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 59414 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing apache2-bin (2.4.41-4ubuntu3.15) ...
Removing apache2-data (2.4.41-4ubuntu3.15) ...
Removing apache2-utils (2.4.41-4ubuntu3.15) ...
Removing libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3:amd64 (1.6.1-4ubuntu2.2) ...
Removing libaprutil1-ldap:amd64 (1.6.1-4ubuntu2.2) ...
Removing libaprutil1:amd64 (1.6.1-4ubuntu2.2) ...
Removing libapr1:amd64 (1.6.5-1ubuntu1) ...
Removing libjansson4:amd64 (2.12-1build1) ...
Removing liblua5.2-0:amd64 (5.2.4-1.1build3) ...
Removing ssl-cert (1.0.39) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.12) ...
imran123@vm2:~$ apache2 -v
-bash: /usr/sbin/apache2: No such file or directory
```

[image]

Comment: Let me check your solution

Comment: When I run the 1st command `sudo systemctl status apache2`, I received this [result](https://i.imgur.com/I8Zrqwq.png). could you please tell what it states as I'm new to linux commands & outputs.

Comment: Then Purge Apache and its Configuration Files use -> `sudo apt-get purge apache2` then Remove Residual Apache Directories `sudo rm -rf /etc/apache2` -> remove binary `sudo rm /usr/sbin/apache2`
-> Check for Any Remaining Files: any `which apache2` If it returns a path, remove that path:
`sudo rm /path/to/apache2` and then `apache2 -v`

Comment: like [this](https://i.imgur.com/R49w9KM.png)

Comment: Hey @Imran, Thank you so much. It worked with the above commands given the comment and received the output like you shown in above comment. Appreciate your efforts for the prompt response and solving within an hour. ***Great Efforts, Knowledge & Problem Solving - Imran***

Comment: Could you please tell me why I got that type of result when I entered 1st command `sudo systemctl status apache2` and what does that result mean

Comment: the service is prevented from starting (masked), and it is currently in a failed state. The failure seems to be related to issues with mount name spacing and a missing directory.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Imran. Really appreciated your knowledge & prompt response in Public community/forum.

Comment: @TheMassacre: Good to accept the solution if it has helped. This is for the benefit of the SO Community, refer SO link – 
SPT - Who are you? Why are you posting this for someone's answer.

Comment: @SPT, Not Sure whether you are moderator or common. Make Sure you encourage the questioners also by upvoting their questions if you wanna ask for the solutions acceptance.